# PHP e MySQL: base64_decode dentro do SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Tenho um INSERT que registra no banco com o base64_encode(), funcionando perfeitamente.

```
"INSERT INTO Atendimento_Campo_Prontuario (
                        acpr_id,
                        acpr_apro_id,
                        acpr_valor
                        )
                    VALUES (
                        :acprn_id,
                        :acprapro_id,
                        :acpr_valor)";
$p_sql->bindValue(':acpr_valor', base64_encode($acpr->getAcpr_valor()));
```

Agora preciso do base64_decode para buscar essa informação, alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Teria alguma maneira de passar o base64_decode() dentro do SELECT como eu faço com o acpr_id?

```
"SELECT * FROM  table WHERE table.acpr_id =:acpr_id";

$p_sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
$p_sql->bindValue(':acpr_id', $acpr->getAcpr_id());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso, antes de buscar a informação no banco de dados criptografe a variável, assim como fez no insert.

Parar mostrar a variável na tela depois que buscar o resultado, descriptografa ela utilizando

echo base64_decode($valor);

Comment: Utilizar o base64_decode para cada vez que chamar a variável na view?

Comment: utilize no controller antes de enviar para a view, mas seria a mesma coisa